# Odd EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling contactTestBetweenBody

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a 3D scene created in scene kit comprising an area surrounded by invisible walls and I want to lob physics objects into this area in such a way that they can't escape once they're in. I had a mind to achieve this in the following fashion:

1. Create a wall object
2. Create a 'solidifier' that fits neatly inside the walls
3. Set each object's `isInScene` variable to false
4. Lob them in the vague direction of the solidifier
5. Upon each update, if an object is touching the solidifier but is not touching the walls, I change its collision mask to include the walls and set `isInScene` to true so I don't have to check it again.

This often seems to work very well, but every so often (and sadly quite often) I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error out of nowhere. The offending method seems to be contactTestBetweenBody, which I am using to determine when an object is touching either the walls or solidifier at times when normal collision detection is turned off. This is necessary to prevent the objects simply bouncing off the outside of the wall object.

Here's a small snippet of code to illustrate. Incidentally, 'objects' is a structure that retains a reference to the node along with other useful details:

```
if let solid = solidifier?.physicsBody, let wall = walls?.physicsBody {
    let world = scene.physicsWorld
    for i in 0 ..< objects.count {
        if objects[i].isInScene == false, let body = objects[i].node.physicsBody {
            let contactSolidifier = world.contactTestBetweenBody(body, andBody: solid, options: nil)
            if contactSolidifier != nil {
                let contactWall = world.contactTestBetweenBody(body, andBody: wall, options: nil)
                if contactWall == nil {
                    objects[i].isInScene = true
                    body.collisionBitMask = CollisionMask.allSolids.rawValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue: EXC_BAD_ISSUE when using the `contactTest` :s

Answer (score 0):

I found a much, much better solution to the problem that I just plain didn't think of for some reason. Forget about this ridiculously convoluted means of keeping the objects in view. Instead, just make the area you want to retain the objects within and reverse its facet direction and normals.

What I didn't realise was that SceneKit uses backface culling on collision detection too, so if a physics object hits the OUTSIDE of an object that is inside out it will pass clean through.

I would still be interested to know the reason for the bad access error still though, as the contact test methods are useful and I may want to use them for other reasons in the future.